# Is there a way to output the distortions for each row when creating clusters with kmeans?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

Here's a little bit of the code:

```
df_tr_std = stats.zscore(df_tr[clmns])

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='k-means++',n_init=10,max_iter=300,tol=1e-04,random_state=0)
y_km = km.fit_predict(df_tr_std)
```

I tried referencing inertial_ but that's the total distortion. This following code works to calculate the individual distances:

```
distance = euclidean_distances(km.cluster_centers_, df_tr_std)
```

but it separates the distances into 3 arrays (or however many number of clusters I create). Is there a way to do this without separating by labels/cluster?

I would like to extend my original dataset with a column of the distances so that I can identify the largest distances. I also wanted the closest distances but I was able to find that using this code:

```
closest, _ = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(km.cluster_centers_, df_tr_std)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use the cluster centroids as well as the labels to index into the cluster centroids to get what each example is represented as.  You can then compute the distortion of each example separately.  Recall that the distortion or inertia of a K-Means clustering result is simply the sum of squared differences between an example and it's corresponding representative centroid.  To compute the individual distortion values, you simply find the representative centroid of each example, then find the sum of squared differences of the components.  The total distortion is the sum of all of these values.

Therefore:

```
cluster_centers = km.cluster_centers_
centroids = cluster_centers[y_km]
distortion = ((df_tr_std - centroids)**2.0).sum(axis=1)
```

The first line of code accesses the cluster centres of your fitted K-means model.  The second line of code obtains the representative centroids per example using the labels output from the fit result.  With the last line, you can then compute the distortion by subtracting each row or example of your input and its representative centroid component wise, square each element, then sum along each row.

It may be convenient to do this in one line without the need for temporary variables:

```
distortion = ((df_tr_std - km.cluster_centers_[y_km])**2.0).sum(axis=1)
```

This now gives you the computed distortion per example.  Concretely, `distortion` is a `N,` NumPy array with `N` being the number of examples in your dataset.  Each element corresponds to the distortion contributed by the corresponding example to the overall distortion.

To verify, you can check the `km.inertia_` which is the total distortion matches the sum of the distortion array computed in the last line, so check `distortion.sum()` and `km.inertia_`.

As a reproducible example:

```
In [27]: import numpy as np

In [28]: from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

In [29]: df_tr_std = np.random.rand(1000,3)

In [30]: km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='k-means++',n_init=10,max_iter=300,tol=
    ...: 1e-04,random_state=0)

In [31]: y_km = km.fit_predict(df_tr_std)

In [32]: distortion = ((df_tr_std - km.cluster_centers_[y_km])**2.0).sum(axis=1)

In [33]: km.inertia_
Out[33]: 147.01626670004867

In [34]: distortion.sum()
Out[34]: 147.01626670004865
```

Take note that there are some slight differences towards the trailing end of the value and this is due to numerical precision, but you can assure yourself that we have computed the distortion of each example separately.

Once you have the array of distortions, you can add an additional column that represents these in your data frame and you can locate which row gave you the largest or smallest distortion as you wish.